# Как сортировать столбец в объединенных таблицах?

Tags: база-данных, select, sql

```
SELECT *
FROM   COMPETITION_RESULTS_1500MFS
ORDER BY MESTO ASC
UNION
SELECT *
FROM   COMPETITION_RESULTS_800MFS
ORDER BY MESTO ASC  
UNION
SELECT *
FROM   COMPETITION_RESULTS_50MFS
ORDER BY MESTO ASC
```

Comment: @d1mex, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 2):

При объединении нескольких запросов через UNION параметры сортировки задаются после последнего запроса.

```
SELECT * FROM COMPETITION_RESULTS_800MFS
UNION 
SELECT * FROM COMPETITION_RESULTS_50MFS 
ORDER BY MESTO ASC
```